# Internet Permission for Location Updates

Tags: android, location

Do I really need Internet Permission to get the current Location through either GPS or Network Provider.

I run the below code without giving Internet Permission .It is working fine.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.practice"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />  

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.practice.LocationActivity" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.practice.AlarmReceiver" >
        </receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

**LocationService.java**

```
package com.example.location;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class LocationService implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;
    private boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    private boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    private boolean canGetLocation = false;

    private Location location;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public LocationService(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        location = getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {

        try {

            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); 


            Log.i("network ", isNetworkEnabled+"");
            Log.i("GPS ", isGPSEnabled+""); 

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

            } else {
                canGetLocation = true;
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.i("GPS", "GPS");
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }

                    }
                }
                    if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                        Log.i("location", location+"");
                        if (location == null) {
                            Log.i("Location Manager", locationManager+""); 
                            if (locationManager != null) {
                                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                                Log.i("NETWORK", "NETWORK");

                                location = locationManager
                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER); 

                                if (location != null) {
                                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return location;
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return canGetLocation;
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

}
```

**LocationActivity.java**

```
package com.example.practice;

import com.example.location.LocationService;

import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LocationActivity extends Activity {

    LocationService locationService;
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);

        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_location);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              locationService=new LocationService(LocationActivity.this);
              if(locationService.canGetLocation())
              {
                  Location location=locationService.getLocation();
                  Toast.makeText(LocationActivity.this, location.getLatitude()+ "  "+location.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


              }
            }  
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.location, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question?

Comment: No, he's identified that it works on at least one version of Android.  Presumably he wants to know whether the same applies to all of them, which is an entirely different matter and not one that can easily be answered experimentally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will work as you added the location permission and also see this on developers site http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: So No need for giving internet permission for getting the Current Location right? but I have red the some blogs. they are requesting to give internet permission. I dont know why?http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/  ,             http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

Comment: and also why Inbuilt Map Application  gives  " Data Connection is Unavailale " error when i disables internet connection

Comment: @saravanan change the permission to ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION instead of ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION  and run your app and tell me what happens?

Comment: You said " and also why Inbuilt Map Application gives " Data Connection is Unavailale " error when i disables internet connection" because they have added Network State permission in their app manifest file, that detects internet is available on the device or not.

Comment: I have set the Permission to  ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and commented the below lines in my code                                    //isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);        since GPS requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION .  Now my code works fine!!